# Cannot create StrongOps alerts

Tags: node.js, heroku, strongloop

I have node.js application on Heroku baked with Strongloop's Loopback. Strongloop heroku addon is active and I can see some information on the dashboard about cpu load etc. But try to create alert (by clicking exclamation sign, filling up appropriate information, then clicking "add" button) doesn't work for me: I see no alert created on the "alerts" tab.

Nevertheless, if I do "slc strongops" and run this application locally on my machine (instead of Heroku) and then I go to https://strongops.strongloop.com/ops/dashboard, I can successfully create alerts and see them in appropriate tab for my local application.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?